# wordpress visual editor not generating html p tags for the paragraphs

Tags: wordpress

wordpress visual editor not generating html `<p>` tags for the paragraphs and thus non formatted content gets saved in the database. It results in showing all paragraphs together on frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this plug-in: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/

After activation goto **Settings** > **TinyMCE Advanced**

Under **Advanced Options** check '**Keep paragraph tags**'